# addChildViewControllerで追加した画面のボタンで、追加元のLabelを変更する方法

Tags: swift, uikit

swiftプログラムを作成しております。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような画面になりますが、「Button」を押すと、「Label」が"変更しました"に変更したいと思っています。しかし、「Button」を押しても変化しません。

PageMenuライブラリ([https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)を使っています](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu)%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99)。CAPSPageMenu.swiftをインポートしています。

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ParentLabel: UILabel!
    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

        let controller1 : SecondView = SecondView(nibName: "SecondView", bundle: nil)
        controller1.title = "2nd View"
        controllerArray.append(controller1)
        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
            .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
            .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.orangeColor()),
            .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
            .MenuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13.0)!),
            .MenuHeight(40.0),
            .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
            .CenterMenuItems(true)
        ]
        pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 50, self.view.frame.width, 100), pageMenuOptions: parameters)
        self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
        self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
        pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

SecondView.swift

```
import UIKit

class SecondView: UIViewController {

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func changeLabel(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let vc :ViewController = self.parentViewController as? ViewController {
            vc.ParentLabel.text = "変更しました"
        }
    }
```

上記のコードの通りです。
どうやら

```
if let vc :ViewController = self.parentViewController as? ViewController {
```

で型キャストに失敗しているようです。

```
if let vc :ViewController = self.presentedViewController as? ViewController {
```

に変えてもダメでした。

追加元のLabelを変更するにはどうしたらいいのでしょう？ご存知の方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PageMenuのソースコードリーディングをしましょう。

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = [vc1, vc2, vc3]

    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 50), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

`ViewController.swift`では複数のビューコントローラから`CAPSPageMenu`を生成しています。ここで重要なのは、`ViewController`の直接の子となっているのは、 **`CAPSPageMenu`であって、個々の子`ViewController`ではない** ということです。

これがなぜかというと、省メモリ化のためです。実際に`view`を生成する必要があるのは、現在表示しているページとその前後分、せいぜい3ページ分の`ViewController`だけです。最初から10や100ページ分の`ViewController`の`view`をインスタンス化してしまうと非常に重くなるので、`view`の生成および破棄を適時行う必要があります。その面倒を見てくれるのが、PageMenuライブラリなのです。

つまり、

- RootViewController

  - CAPSPageMenu

    - ChildViewController

の階層構造となっており、このためルートの`ViewController`に対して何らかの処理をするのであれば、以下のコードのように「親の親」を取得する必要があります。

```
@IBAction func click(sender: UIButton) {
    if let vc = self.parentViewController?.parentViewController as? ViewController {
        vc.label.text = "changed"
    }
}
```

これはあまり良い方法とは言えないので、`CAPSPageMenuDelegate`を利用して、現在表示しているページに`delegate`を持たせたり、ちょっと大げさになりますが`UINotificationCenter`を利用するといった方法が好ましいかもしれません。

Comment: できました。またdelegateを持たせる方法がよくわかりませんでしたが、実装としてUINotificationCenterを利用する方法をとりました。こちらもとても助かる情報をいただき感謝しています。